Is there a way to install grub with a default password set when installing Ubuntu?
looking at the previous answers for how to set a password for GRUB 'edit' and 'console' commands, I saw that when you update your GRUB, this gets overwritten.
I was wondering if there was a way of (when installing Ubuntu) setting a GRUB configuration always to keep this password.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords
